# over loading, missfiring

Tags: engine, buick

My car is missing particularly whenever ur going up hill or in any case where u have to give it more gas. I've replaced plugs, caps, Cool Pak's. Ignition module, tps sensor, mass air flow sensor and still have the same problem it almost cleared up for a few hrs after I replaced the ignition module. Could the crank sensor be causing all this? My car is a 1997 but Buick skylark 2.4 limited addition.   Thank you

Comment: I think if the crank sensor were causing it, your car would not be running at all. Question is, is it misfiring, or is it pinging (knocking)? Secondly, if you replaced the TPS, are you sure it was calibrated correctly? Have you pulled codes from the ECM? If so, what are (were) they?

Comment: My sister-in-law Nissan frontier did same thing I put everything in it was hard to start .no power slip light on it was driving here crazy .took it all way to Las Vegas from KY  doing the no power missing all that .fix got it back KY put crankshaft sensor no more problems. It was getting hot going ground.check can shaft should nhave sensor there .  Have you checked fire on plugs should be blue  . pressure monitor fuel pump you'll have to check book .gas filter good  has to be crankshaft  computer.h I just no what I've been through with them.hopr you fix it good luck